# .htacces Appears only html with no CSS or PHP

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I've been wondering on the internet on how to work with htacces(really hard to learn it). And when I was lurking in the internet, I found this: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Well, I inserted my url(working on localhost):
`empresa.com/index.php?p=sub_artigo&id=1&cat=Mercearia`

and it gave me this(with all options by default):
`http://empresa.com/sub_artigo/5/Mercearia.html`

And the .htacces code was this:
`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$        /index.php?p=$1&id=$2&cat=$3 [L]`

And when I generate the url in php I do

```
<a href=\"sub_artigo/".$response2['ID_sub_artigo']."/".$response2['url'].".html\">$response2[nome_sub_artigo]</a>
```

And then, when I click the button, it appears like, only html.
example: http://s14.postimg.org/wr137fx4x/htacces_error.jpg

Any idea what is happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using relative links for your assets (images, javascript, css).

That means that when you look for `css/my_stylesheet.css`, from the new url, the browser will request a url like `http://empresa.com/sub_artigo/5/css/my_stylesheet.css`.

The easiest solution is to always use absolute urls for your assets, like `/css/my_stylesheet.css`, etc.

Comment: Just a little thing. When I click different links, why do they accumulate in the url ?

Comment: @Sashka The url of the current page is used as the base url and as soon as you use a relative link, it is prepended to that url. If you use an absolute url, only the domain is prepended, just hover over any link on your page and check the complete url in the status bar of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is outputting relative paths to the style sheets.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Given your example input URL, this causes the browser to look for a stylesheet at the following URL:

```
http://empresa.com/sub_artigo/5/styles.css
```

This is because the browser doesn't know that the URL has been rewritten - it believes it is viewing a file in a subdirectory that doesn't really exist.

Instead you should use an absolute path, such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
```

Notice the leading `/` on the path? This will tell the browser to look from the root of the domain:

```
http://empresa.com/styles.css
```

In this way you can still decouple your HTML from the protocol and domain/port (so you aren't tied to `http://empresa.com`) but the path will always be the same regardless of the URL that was used to reach the referencing page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /empresa.com/index.php?p=$1&id=$2&cat=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Still the same, doesn't change.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that that is the problem as the css file (and other assets) will not have the `.html` extension.

Comment: Yes it's your answer which right. Besides, I have often the same problem.